# Cheated by a friend using remote login

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, sudo, users, remote-access

Me and my flatmate connect over the same network. Recently, I brought a new PC. Since I didn't want to spend money on Windows, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it.

Since my friend knew way more about Ubuntu than compared to me, for a joke, he set the `sudo` password and logged me in as another user. Since I did not know much, I accepted what he did.

Now that I started learning Ubuntu, I found that he was remotely accessing my PC from his laptop which runs Ubuntu 18.04. Since I don't know the `sudo` password and my friend is reluctant to tell me, I'm in a mess. Please help me.

Comment: wipe the computer, reinstall, load your backups. don't let this other person touch it.

Answer (score 4):

if you installed ubuntu by yourself, the user that you created during installation gets sudo access.

you can always reinstall too..